# When value is greater than 1, do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a variable named `countTicked` that is storing an integer of how many `relatedBoxes` there are on the page.

I need an `if` statement that does something when the value of `countTicked` is greater than 1.

```
if (!$(clickedCheckBox).is(':checked'))
{
     //do something
} 
else
{
    var selectedDots = $(currentMap).find('div.' + checkBoxID);
    var relatedCheckBoxes = $(selectedDots).attr('class');        
    var countTicked = $(relatedCheckBoxes).filter(':checked');

    if (countTicked > 1)
    {
        //do one thing
    } 
    else
    {
        //do something else
    }      
}
```

I have implemented the changes you guys have provided. But my second IF statement still doesnt work. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: What is relatedBoxes? names of the elements? class? a variable?

Comment: Since you're using the `length` property of a jQuery object, you don't have to use `parseInt` (it's already a number).

Comment: When you use parseInt, make sure to pass the second variable as well, like this in your case: parseInt($(relatedBoxes).length, 10); otherwise weird things can happen.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson That's generally a good advice, but it doesn't matter in this case, as the `length` property of a jQuery object is a number, in base-10.

Comment: `$` is just a function -- an alias for `jQuery` in this case. So, ask yourself: what does/should `jQuery(countTicked)` do?

Comment: @Rob W Good point, wasn't looking at the value he was parsing. Thanks, +1

Comment: relatedBoxes are checkboxes. I needed to get the length and if the value was greater than 1, I wanted to do one thing, and if it wasn't greater, do another.

Comment: How did you get get this relatedBoxed var?

Comment: right im going to post up the full code now

Comment: I have updated the code, apologies for not being clear enough in the first place, thought a snippet would do. I have implemented the updated changes and am very grateful for that, but the second IF statement still doesnt work.

Comment: Debug it to see where is the first bug and update your question once more.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you just missing the length property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do use use the $ sign? what is relatedBoxes?

```
var countTicked = parseInt($(relatedBoxes).length);

if (countTicked > 1)
{
    //do something

} 
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

Update: you have to use the length to get the number of elements.

```
var countTicked = $(relatedCheckBoxes).filter(':checked').length;
```

Comment: Who uses `parseInt` for parsing integers? :)

Comment: thank you so much gdoron, got there in the end! your right, the length property was missing. +1

Comment: @CecilTheodore. glad I could help. BTW, +1 means upvote, you just accepted the answer. two different things. **=)**

Comment: I upvoted earlier, you were right by suggesting I didnt need the $ on the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this as if condition:

```
if (countTicked > 1)
```

countTicked contains an integer, no need to put it in a jquery object.

Comment: And the parseInt in the first line, is not necessary too, cause the .length attribute always contains an integer.

Answer (score 1):

it should be :

```
  var countTicked = parseInt($(relatedBoxes).length);

            if (countTicked > 1)
            {
                //do something

            } else
            {
                //do something else
            }
```

as you are using  `countTicked`  as variable. No need to use it as a jquery object

Answer (score 1):

`$(relatedCheckBoxes).filter(':checked')` is a jQuery object, which has `length` property.
So in order to know amount of ticked checkboxes, use

```
var countTicked = $(relatedCheckBoxes).filter(':checked').length
```

`parseInt` isn't obligated.

Comment: ok thanks thats helpful but im still not understanding why my second IF statement isnt working.